# Ajax submit form (woocommerce)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

so for the woocommerce, is there a way to submit the product order form by ajax so that users are not redirected to the order-detail page?

I simply want to show "Success" or other popup layout to indicate that the order has been submitted without redirection or refreshing the page.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you don't think users would like to see the order details of what they're going to be charged?

Comment: Well, it will be in a case where they already purchased it. Once they confirm and submit their purchase, they would normally redirect to their "order-detail" page which shows what they purchased. But instead, I would simply want them to stay in the product page with an indication that they have successfully purchased it.

Comment: If you want remove the order content from thank you page you can simply override the thankyou.php page template or on woocommerce_thankyou hook you can redirect the user to product page.